# Attempted to load class "PDO" from namespace

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony, pdo

when I run this line

```
$pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydata','root', null);
```

I get this error

```
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException]                 
  Attempted to load class "PDO" from namespace "check\roomsBundle\Command".  
  Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

I tried to add this line to my parametrs.yml

```
database_driver: pdo_pgsql
and 
database_driver: pdo_mysql
```

but I still get this error I using symfony2.8 and mysql

```
class SocketCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
      //some code here
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {

        //somecode here

        $pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydata', 'root', null);

}
```

Comment: Why do you add `pdo_pgsql` but use `mysql`?

Comment: @u_mulder i tried to use it and tried to use database_driver: pdo_mysql to i will edit my question

Comment: Maybe it's cache? Try to clear cache before continue. Because syntax is right

Comment: @AlexSlipknot i cleared the cache and i still get the error

Comment: maybe you haven't extension pdo?

Comment: @AlexSlipknot yes how to add extension pdo in linux ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you just haven't PDO extension because syntax is right.
On Ubuntu/Debian you should be able to install the necessary PDO parts from apt using

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

or 
`apt-get install php5-mysql` on old repo

Also you have to enable it in php.ini: `extension=pdo_mysql.so`

But in case when you have extension you can try to add

```
 use \PDO;
```

in your bundle

Comment: E: Package 'php5-mysql' has no installation candidate

Comment: i get this error E: Package 'php5-mysql' has no installation candidate

Comment: On newest repo you can use **apt-get install php-mysql**

Comment: Please look in phpinfo() for PDO extension. What does it say?

Comment: You have to write some test.php. And put <?php phpinfo(); ?> inside. Then execute it to see result

Comment: mysql, pgsql, sqlite  enabled

Comment: i found this line to API Extensions  mysqli,pdo_mysql

Comment: i still get the same proplem

Comment: try to add **use \PDO** in your bundle

Comment: i hope if you add ";" to use \PDO; in your answer